# Multiple Button Click in Order (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, I have a button grid like a chess board (8x8; 64 buttons).
When I click on a button at first, I want to make it Green (and disabled) and copy its text to a TextBox named as 'Green'. And when I click on another button after that, I want to make it Red (and disabled) and copy its text to a TextBox named as 'Red'.
How should I do that? (by order (first and last) and in one handler).

Please check the given picture. Consider I click on E2 first, it becomes Green and disabled. After that I click on F2, it becomes Red and disabled.

[image]

Comment: Show us the code that you've already got.

Comment: Which code would you like to see? I couldn't do anything about handling them all. @Carra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register the following event to all the buttons:

```
private int buttonClickCount; //set to 0 in constructor
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonClickCount++; //add 1
            switch (buttonClickCount)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.Red.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
                    (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.Green.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
                    (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                //add other cases here
                default:
                    buttonClickCount--; //add some logic if something unexpected happens
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Alright, this one is for click by order and changing the color. Thank you so much for that! And how should I handle all the buttons? I mean, do I have to make this for all buttons one by one?

Comment: Select all the buttons in the designer and navigate to the event section in the properties. Copy the name of the event (in this case button1_Click) next to "Click". The event will be fired whenever a button that has registered this event is clicked